# Error message with exactLRT to test for suitability of random intercept in lmer model

Tags: r, random, lmer

I'm trying to use exactLRT to see whether I should include a random intercept in my model.
Below is a reproducible example:

> library(lmer)
>
> m.intercept <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days+(1|Subject), data=sleepstudy)
>
> m0 <- lm(Reaction ~ Days, data=sleepstudy)
>
> exactLRT(m=m.intercept, m0=m0)

I get the following error message: "Error in exactLRT(m = m.intercept, m0 = m0) : 
  multiple random effects in model - 
                 exactLRT needs 'm' with only a single random effect."

However, as far as I understand, I've included a single random effect in m.intercept (namely, random intercept).

Any idea about what is the issue?

In case it's useful:

> R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)
>
> locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
>   LC_TIME=en_CA.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_CA.UTF-8      [5]
>   LC_MONETARY=en_CA.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_CA.UTF-8
>   LC_PAPER=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                   [9]
>   LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
>   LC_MEASUREMENT=en_CA.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages: [1] splines   grid      stats     graphics 
>   grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:  [1] RLRsim_3.0      MuMIn_1.10.0
>   psych_1.4.5     WriteXLS_3.5.0  reshape2_1.2.2  languageR_1.4.1  [7]
>   e1071_1.6-3     HLMdiag_0.2.5   gdata_2.13.3    psy_1.1
>   car_2.0-19      ggplot2_0.9.3.1 [13] date_1.2-34     plyr_1.8.1
>   Hmisc_3.14-4    Formula_1.1-1   survival_2.37-7 lattice_0.20-29 [19]
>   foreign_0.8-62  lmerTest_2.0-6  lme4_1.1-6      Rcpp_0.11.2
>   Matrix_1.1-5
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] bitops_1.0-6
>   caTools_1.17        class_7.3-11        cluster_1.15.3
>   colorspace_1.2-4     [6] dichromat_2.0-0     digest_0.6.4
>   gplots_2.13.0       gtable_0.1.2        gtools_3.4.0        [11]
>   KernSmooth_2.23-13  labeling_0.2        latticeExtra_0.6-24
>   MASS_7.3-37         minqa_1.2.3         [16] munsell_0.4.2
>   nlme_3.1-119        nnet_7.3-8          numDeriv_2012.9-1
>   pbkrtest_0.3-8      [21] proto_0.3-10        RColorBrewer_1.0-5 
>   RcppEigen_0.3.2.1.2 scales_0.2.3        stats4_3.1.2        [26]
>   stringr_0.6.2       tools_3.1.2

Comment: It worked for me in a clean session. Your version of `lme4` is a little out of date (current is `1.1-7`). Restart R, update `lme4`, and try again?

Comment: Thank you. I tried that and it works only if I don't load the other packages. So I tried to load the packages one by one to see which one is interfering, and it's `lmerTest`. In case someone else faces the same issue...

Comment: It looks like `lmerTest` has its own `lmer` function. If you wanted both packages at the same time, you could use `m.intercept <- lme4::lmer(Reaction ~ Days+(1|Subject), data=sleepstudy)`.

Comment: Thanks. That's even better than unloading the package. I'll modify my answer below to take your suggestion into account.

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to @alexforrence for pointing me in the right direction. The code above does not work if `lmerTest` is loaded (I guess `exactLRT` doesn't accept objects of class `merModLmerTest`, but only of class `merMod`) or used to run the mixed-effects model.

So the following works and allows `lmerTest` to be loaded:

> library(lmer)
>
> library(RLRsim)
>
> data(sleepstudy)
>
> m.intercept <- lme4::lmer(Reaction ~ Days+(1|Subject), data=sleepstudy)
>
> m0 <- lm(Reaction ~ Days, data=sleepstudy)
>
> exactLRT(m=m.intercept, m0=m0)

Sorry if answering my own question isn't in the rules of this forum, I just didn't want to leave it hanging now that I figured it out.